# Picturebox OnMouseClick coordinates relevance to the control and not the form

Tags: c#, winforms, coordinates, picturebox, mousedown

I have a windows form, inside it there is a PictureBox control, I populate the control with an image.

When went to the MouseDown event and was able to get the coordinates but in terms of the whole form and not just the control, so instead of getting a coordinate of `(10,15)` I get `(110,40)` that is because it got me the mouse position of the form.

Can I get a `coordinates enclosed to the PictureBox` control only?

Comment: would u please show the code of mouse event?

Answer (score 2):

Try this .........

```
private void PictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
  int x = e.x - PictureBox1.Left ;
  int y = e.y - PictureBox1.Top ;

  MessageBox.Show(x.tostring + "," + y.tostring); 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `x - PictureBox.Left` and `y - PictureBox.Top`.

OR

Write the code in the event handler for the PictureBox, not the form.